# WPF OnNotifyPropertyChange Throws a null exception when instantiating an object

Tags: c#, wpf

I just recently added a field to the database and had to update the model from database using EF. However, the model shows all the correct fields and their types. The `Estimate` class does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well. This was working prior to updating the database, but not sure what went south

When traveling in the debugger from:

```
CurrentEstimate = new Estimate();
```

To (as this property is changing):

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I get a null reference exception.

propertyName is "CurrentEstimate" and `CurrentEstimate` is not `null` once it gets to the `NotifyPropertyChanged` function.

Implemnetation of CurrentEstimate:

```
    private Estimate _estimate;
    public Estimate CurrentEstimate
    {
        get { return _estimate; }
        set { _estimate = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Comment: It is throwing it at PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

Comment: It shouldn't. Please provide a repo: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mm8 I do not feel comfortable throwing this up as it is client based work. And it is definitely throwing the exception at that line.

Comment: I doubt it. Are you debugging a release build?

Comment: Nope. And I tried creating a separate project with the code snippets to reproduce the error, yet that is where it works.

Comment: Are you sure you set dataContext?

Comment: @mm8 figured it out. It was being thrown from a converter used in the xaml, but the propertychanged line was throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the exception was being thrown at:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

A custom converter was the culprit.